# how can we find the complexity of merge sort with an array of size 16

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, asymptotic-complexity

I have an array of size 16 and have to find its `theta` and `big Oh`

general case is `nlogn` but what will it be for specific case.

```
73  3   69  88  36  56  44  63  14  60  80  84  6   80  55  62
```

Comment: By theta do you mean Ө, or by any chance do you mean time complexity equation T(n) = f(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array size or its composition/pattern don't affect the merge sort technique. So it is going to be same for 16-elements array as well. [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) will anyway at first divide the array, then compare and merge.

Comment: The data pattern will affect the number of compares, but the number of moves remains the same, and since big O doesn't consider lower order terms, time complexity for big O is still O(n log(n)).